# Converting a UTC date/time string to a readable EST in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I've looked for this answer in multiple locations and couldn't find anything. I have a sheet that is pulling XML data from the National Weather Service. The data is time sensitive and stamped with a UTC date/time in the following format:

```
2017-06-09T13:15:00-00:00
```

This is for a public facing application, so I'd like to convert that UTC date/time to US Eastern Time (UTC-4). I'm not sure how to begin to approach this. Do I start by trying to split that UTC data up into something the time formatting in Google sheets will recognize, and how would I accomplish that?

If anyone has some experience with this, I'd greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=datevalue(left(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(mid(A1,12,8))-4/24
```

and adjust for summer time to suit.

Comment: This worked well for me. Thank you! To adjust for DST I added a new cell on my sheet where I have the hour calculation. Then in the formula I reference that cell. So all I need to do is change that value.